# Directions via Intent Automatically

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I building an app that contains many addresses. A user can select an address in a listview. This should automatically show a user directions to that address from the users current location.

```
 String uri = "geo:"+ selectedAddress.getLat+","+getLng();
 StartActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(uri)));
```

I know all this does is show the location of the specified co-ords.

How would i go about showing the directions to the location from the users current location?

Comment: I don't think you can; if you look at [this list](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html), you'll see that the only available intents for Google Maps is how to show a location, what you have done in your code.

Answer (score 1):

> How would i go about showing the directions to the location from the users current location?

As @Frxstrem indicated, there is no documented and supported `Intent` to bring up directions.

Answer (score 1):

ask the user for the place and do the following way:

```
String place="";//user gives the place.
String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="+place;
Intent drn = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,  Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(drn);
```

Google will automatically take the current user location as starting point and give directions